# Prolog converting text to number and doing arithmatic operations

Tags: prolog

I working in prolog for first time.
I am trying to convert operations in text.
Such as, 
THREE + THREE = SIX
should return true.
I tried this.
I am getting error on last line and when I try add(ONE,ONE,TWO) it returns false instead of true.

```
numericValue(ONE, 1).
numericValue(TWO, 2).
numericValue(THREE, 3).
numericValue(FOUR, 4).
numericValue(FIVE, 5).
numericValue(SIX, 6).
numericValue(SEVEN, 7).
numericValue(EIGHT, 8).
numericValue(ZERO, 0).
numericValue(NINE, 9).


add(num1,num2,num3):-
    numericValue(num1,a),
    numericValue(num2,b),
    numericValue(num3,c),
    (c =:= a+b -> true ; false).

istBiggerThen(XinEng,YinEng) :-
    numericValue(XinEng, X),
    numericValue(YinEng, Y),
    (  X < Y -> true ;  false).

A  + B = C :- add(A,B,C).
```

Error on last line is

```
ERROR: /home/name/prolog_examples/crypt.pl:24:
No permission to modify static procedure `(=)/2'
```

Comment: One major issue you have is that, in Prolog, variables start with a capital letter, and atoms (constants) start lower case. You seem to have this reversed in several places. Also, `=/2` is the built-in unification operator (it's not arithmetic equality of expressions). When you enter `A + B = C :- add(A,B,C)` it's an attempt to redefine what `=/2` means, which isn't allowed.

Answer (score 2):

#### `l`iterals (lower-case) vs. `V`ariabls (upper-case):

as @lurker pointed out, you have your atoms and variables mixed up. So your facts should look something like this:

```
text_to_number(one, 1).
text_to_number(two, 2).
text_to_number(three, 3).
%% etc...
```

while your rules will need to use variables, like so:

```
add(A_Text, B_Text, C_Text) :-
    text_to_number(A_Text, A_Num),
    text_to_number(B_Text, B_Num),
    C_Num is A_Num + B_Num,
    text_to_number(C_Text, C_Num).

bigger_than(A_Text, B_Text) :-
    text_to_number(A_Text, A_Num),
    text_to_number(B_Text, B_Num),
    A_Num > B_Num.
```

The reason reason why `add(ONE, ONE, TWO)` turns out false is because your original rule for `add/3` only defines relationships between the atoms `num1, num2, num3, a, b, c`. When you query `add(ONE, ONE, TWO)` Prolog tries to unify the variables with the atoms in the head of your rule, which is `add(num1, num2, num3)`.  Because you have `ONE` as the first and second argument of your query, this unification is impossible, since `ONE = ONE` but `num1 \= num2`. As there are no further rules or facts for `add/3`, the query simply returns `false`.

---

#### Using the pattern (|Condition| -> true ; false):

Statements in the body of a clause (i.e., to the right of the `:-` operator) is evaluated to be either true or false, so you will almost never need to use the pattern `(|Condition| -> true ; false)`. E.g. `C_Num is A_Num + B_Num` is true iff `C_Num` can be unified with the sum of `A_Num` and `B_Num`, or else it is false, in which case Prolog will start back tracking.

---

#### Using `=:=/2` vs. `is/2`:

`=:=/2` checks for the equality of its first argument with the value of its second argument, which can be an arithmetical expression that can be evaluated using `is/2`. Query `?- X =:= 2 + 2` and you'll get an instantiation error, because `=:=/2` cannot *compare* a free variable to a mathematical expression. `is/2`, on the other hand, unifies the variable on the left with the value of the expression on the right: `?- X is 2 + 2. X = 4`.

Your use of `=:=/2` would work (provided you straightened out the variable-atom thing), but your rule describes an inefficient and roundabout solution for the following reason: since `numericValue(Num3,C)` precedes evaluation of the arithmetic, Prolog will first unify `numericValue(Num3,C)` with the first fitting fact, viz. `numericValue(one, 1)` then test if `1 =:= A + B`. When this fails, Prolog will unify with the next fact `numericValue(two, 2)` then test if `2 =:= A + B`, then the next... until it finally happens upon the right value. Compare with my suggested rule: the numeric values `A_Num` and `B_Num` are summed with `C_Num is A_Num + B_Num`, unifying `C_Num` with the sum. Then Prolog unifies `text_to_number(C_Text, C_Num)` with the single fitting fact that has the appropriate value for `C_Num`.

---

#### Defining operators:

When a term appears on the right of a `:-`, or on the top level of the program, is being defined. However, you cannot simply redefine predicates (it can be done, but requires some bookkeeping and special declarations. Cf., `dynamic/1`). Moreover, you wouldn't want to redefine core terms like `+/2` and `=/2`. But you *can* define your own predicates with relative ease. In fact, going crazy with predicate definitions is one of my favorite idle things to do with Prolog (though I've read cautions against using unnecessary operators in practice, since it makes your code recondite).

Operators are declared using `op/3` in a directive. It has the signature `op(+Precedence, +Type, :Name)` (Cf., the [SWI-Prolog documentation](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=operators)):

```
:- op(200, xfx, user:(++)).
:- op(300, yfx, user:(=::=)).

A ++ B =::= C :- add(A, B, C).
```

In action:

```
?- one ++ two  =::= X.
X = three.
```

Comment: tried add(A_Text, B_Text, C_Text) :-
    numericValue(A_Text, A_Num),
    numericValue(B_Text, B_Num),
    C_Num is A_Num + B_Num,
    numericValue(C_Text, C_Num).
Still gives true for add(ONE,ONE,ONE).

Comment: @rbh assuming everything else is right in your code, I assume the *variable* `ONE` is unifying with the atom `zero`, giving you `add(zero, zero, zero).` Is your Prolog top-level not showing you the value of `ONE` that gives the true result? Let me know if I'm mistaken. I'd be happy to take a look at your current code.

Comment: @rbh, if you're trying to test whether the false statement "one + one = one" turns out true, you need to quarry `add(one, one, one)`.

Comment: @rbh are you catching what's being said about names that start with capital letter versus those that start with lower case? `add(ONE, ONE, ONE)` is just like `add(X, X, X)`. `ONE` is a variable. `X` is a variable. That's because they both start with a capital letter. The query `add(ONE, ONE, ONE)` asks what value when added to itself yields itself (using the *variable* `ONE`). The answer will be `ONE = zero`.

Comment: @rbh Sure thing! Glad I could help. Happy Prologing :)

Comment: also about defining operator, if I define as you specified, will it work for 'one ++ two ++ three =::= six' too?

Comment: @rbh Nope! You can see what the structure that expression is by using `display/1`: `=::=(++(one,++(two,three)),six)`. If you just use the above code as is, it will try to pass `++(two, three)` as the second argument to `add/3`, and that won't work. However, this is relatively easy to rectify with a recursive clause that unpacks nested `++/2` terms. You can take that on as an exercise in homoiconic programming, or post another question addressing it!